# Using Typescript interface as HttpParams in the GET request

Tags: angular, http

I have an interface like below

```
export interface ValueList {
  attributeId: number;
  attributeName: string;    
}
```

And my HTTP GET request looks like

```
public getData(columnId: number, columnName: string) {
  const url = './assets/portfoliolist.json';
  return this.httpClient.get(`${url}?attributeId=${columnId}&attributeName=${columnName}`);
}
```

So, basically I am not making use of the interface I defined. I am not really sure how can I use that interface in the GET request to build the query parameters? Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1:**

`getData` is declaring a single parameter (of type `ValueList`) where the values are retrieved using [Destrucuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) as following:

```js
public getData({ attributeId, attributeName }: ValueList) {
  const url = './assets/portfoliolist.json';
  return this.httpClient.get(`${url}?attributeId=${attributeId}&attributeName=${attributeName}`);
}
```

**Option 2:**

```js
public getData(p: ValueList) {
  return this.httpClient.get(`${url}`, { params: new HttpParams({ fromObject: p}) });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it inside the getData method then you may do it like this.

```
public getData(columnId: number, columnName: string) {
    const url = './assets/portfoliolist.json';
    const valueList: ValueList = { attributeId: columnId, attributeName: columnName };

    let httpParams = new HttpParams();
    httpParams = httpParams.append('attributeId', valueList.attributeId.toString());
    httpParams = httpParams.append('attributeName', valueList.attributeName);

    return this.httpClient.get(
      url,
      {
        params: httpParams
      }
    );
  }
```

You may also extract model and query parameter generation code to any place as required and pass query parameter as input to the getData method.